# React app recursively showing within iFrame

Tags: reactjs, webpack, iframe, ref, tradingview-api

Within the app, I am using tradingview's library for charting purposes. However, the entire application is showing within the iframe window, instead of the chart. It is the entire HTML markup, which I can then use to open up another instance of the website. The exact error message is `TypeError: this._innerWindow(...).widgetReady is not a function`, But I believe the issue to be related to browser caching or a webpack issue - perhaps there are similarily named refs or iframes.

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling webpack, both locally and globally.
- Reinstalling a prior working version of the code, which now produces the same error
- Changing the names of the tradingView refs

Tradingview uses `React.createRef()` to link the widget to the app - perhaps this could be a contributing factor as well.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by clearing cached browser files